# How do I find reliable sources listing anime producers?

Tags: anime-production, resources

How do I find official or reliable first-hand sources for which companies produce an anime series? I usually refer to MyAnimeList and Anime News Network, but I cannot find official or company corroboration for some of their articles. Studios usually list their works on their official web page. Is there a similar website for licensors and production companies? Do I need to check the Japanese equivalent of the SEC? The best I could find are third-party non-affiliated sources like independent websites:

[Natalie](https://natalie.mu/comic/news/244019) - Comic/manga discussion site.
[AllCinema](https://www.allcinema.net/cinema/359503) - Blu-ray and listing or schedules.

I want to know which companies pay for and get profit from the show in any way, from streaming to merchandise. I don't think an anime's official website is enough. For example, the website of Zom100 lists the studios and "production company", Shuo Shuisha Production. However, I am not sure if the "production company" refers to a member of the "Zom 100 Production Committee" or just the production assistance company, i.e. the company that handles some administrative jobs.

I want to do research as if I were checking "responsible sourcing." Kyoto Animation Studios is a profitable powerhouse that supposedly avoids [underpaying staff](https://www.forbes.com/sites/laurenorsini/2019/07/19/the-impact-of-kyoto-animation-5-things-you-need-to-know/?sh=75beda5360d6). Do they also avoid working with "black companies" that don't share their good practices? I don't know, because I can't find reliable sources on which companies pay Kyoto Animation.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but things are not that transparent. Otherwise, a particular company can be easily flamed at on the web.

Comment: The ones paying and profiting off of an anime are the ones that are part of the production committee. This isn't necessarily public information.

Comment: To put it simply, a production committee is a joint venture subsidiary company created by various entities with the goal of producing a form of entertainment (this is not just an anime thing). They often receive the name "Title X" Committee / Partners, though sometimes they’ll give them cute in-universe names like "Bunny Mountain Shopping Street" or "Dragon Life Improvement Committee." They’re all essentially the same: some companies coming together to make a production. How they are formed and organized can vary significantly due to the companies involved.